# Can we extract KI from Lugol solution?

Tags: aqueous-solution, extraction

I want to extract the $\ce{KI}$ component of the Lugol solution, is there a method to do it? If not, how can I make a $\ce{KI}$ solution?

Answer (score 3):

As you know you have to remove the others species like $\ce{I2}$ and $\ce{I3-}$. $\ce{I3-}$ I'm quite sure it exists only in solution so simply evaporating the water from Lugol 's solution you should eliminate it. To remove completely $\ce{I2}$ you have to do some others steps.

$\ce{KI}$ is produced industrially by treating iodine with $\ce{KOH}$.(see Wikipedia for [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_iodide#cite_note-Ullmann-3)).

$$ \ce{3I2 + 6KOH -> 5KI + KIO3 + 3H2O}$$

So I think the simple way is to treat Lugol's solution with $\ce{KOH}$ make an ice bath to precipitate $\ce{KIO3}$, filter the solution to remove it and than evaporate water. 
You can also try to remove iodine by means of active carbon I know this method is used to purify water see [ref](http://www.activated-carbon-manufacturer.com/press-release/company-news/111-the-properties-of-activated-carbon.html) and [ref](http://www.lenntech.com/periodic/water/iodine/iodine-and-water.htm#ixzz2exjruJNl).
You can try evaporating the Lugol's solution and re-crystalize it and than eventually  try different solvents to solubilize one of the compounds and leave the other as precipitate but if think is quite difficult to find a better solvent than  water (as you know iodine is very insoluble in water instead $\ce{KI}$ is very soluble).

If you want to make the $\ce{KI}$ from your self here there are two Home experience:

1. [extract potassium iodide from salt](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_extract_potassium_iodide_from_salt)
2. [make $\ce{KI}$ from $\ce{I2}$ and $\ce{KOH}$](http://pharamceuticals.wonderhowto.com/how-to/make-potassium-iodide-ki-from-elemental-iodine-i-and-potassium-hydroxide-koh-0126105/)

Comment: A very clear exposition, can I use other thing than $KOH$ to treat Lugol's solution?

Comment: I don't know I'm sorry! Maybe you can do something with $K_2CO_3$ and/or $KHSO_3$... Of curse if you use active carbon you don't need it...